# CSS div height auto is 0

Tags: css, height, zero

For some reason my fixed header's height is 0. How can I make the header div adopt the height of its child element, header-title? I'm trying to display content below the fixed header with respect to dynamic resolutions. Solutions online were for divs containing floating elements; but that's not what's happening here. CodePen: http://codepen.io/samaraiza/pen/czajq

```
HTML:
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-title"> Cool Title </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content"> Cool Content </div>
</div>

CSS:
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

.header-title {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: One solution is to use Javascript (jQuery or other libraries) to find out the height of the ```.header-title```. Then add the CSS style to the ```.content``` class with ```margin-top:(height of the header-title element)```.

Comment: @AurelienSchlumberger Thanks for the response. Performance is a big deal for what I'm working on. I'm considering JQuery as a very last resort. There's gotta be a CSS solution.

Comment: There's no CSS solution i know of for this problem. As Quentin wrote, `position:fixed` takes it out of the flow so there's no way it can influence the positioning of other elements. You will have to work with javascript (or define a max height for your header and space the content this way. Then its not dynamic, I know)

Comment: @lukasgeiter, so sad :( I'm already abusing JQuery as it is. I was hoping there was something in CSS I wasn't aware of. I'll just give the header a percentage height, and give the contents div a reasonable percentage for its top margin. Thanks again everyone.

Comment: I propose that CSS4 make it possible to relatively position a div and make it so that it stays put when scrolling. Relatively-fixed, haha.

Comment: Well that would be nice!
Also with percentage and margin/padding you have to be really careful. The value is relative to the parents WIDTH (even if you use margin-top) [more info on that](http://mattsnider.com/css-using-percent-for-margin-and-padding/)

Answer (score 1):

All the child elements of the header as `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` (in this case the former).

Elements positioned that way are taken out of normal flow and do not influence the dimensions or position of elements around them.

Set `position: fixed` on the header instead of the header-title.

Comment: thanks for your input. The reason I have the header wrapper is because I want the header and content divs to be vertically stacked. Having a title div without a wrapper gives the div a proper height, but then the contents in the content div begin on the top left corner of the screen, giving off the same result I started with but for a different reason :/ If I could make the contents div be relatively positioned to the fixed header div, that'd be nice...